# Reasons why a JAR on classpath not loaded

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application that is run with the command `java -classpath <longlist of JARs> com.example.MyApp`.

I have the path to a JAR - in this case `liquibase-core-4.4.0.jar` - specified on the classpath. However, on startup the app complains about missing class definitions.

Attaching a debugger I can see that the `URLClassPath` does have this JAR in its `path` list. However, there is no loader for it.

What would cause a JAR to be on the classpath but have no loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot applications have pretty clever system of class path searching, for example it finds jars in `BOOT-INF/lib` - something that a regular java system can't do. So spring has custom class loaders for this purpose.

Now its possible to add an external jar with the help of `LOADER_PATH` environment variable or `loader.path` parameter.

Bottom line, instead of using "standard" java mechanism, consider using "special" spring boot's mechanisms.

[Read the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#appendix.executable-jar.launching) for concrete examples